# Trying to delete old Windows version

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions

When I updated my windows laptop, long ago, from 8.1 to 10 I have since then always 2 operating systems 8.1 and 10 which means Windows 8.1 has its own folder on C drive named as `Windows.old`.

Now I decided to delete the old windows, so according to many websites it is just about deleting the folder like any other folder with granting the permission to the current user which I tried. However, I couldn't ever delete it as it prompts always `permission is needed` or `access denied` even when trying to open `explorer` with admin permission or even when trying to do the deletion using `cmd` with admin permission too!

How could I delete the folder then, could you suggest some methods please?

*NOTE: I tried also to log-in in `safe mode` but didn't worked too.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the `Windows key + E` keyboard shortcut to open File Explorer.
2. From the left pane, click This PC.
3. Under Devices and drives, right-click the drive with the Windows 10 installation, and click Properties.

[image]

4. Click the Disk Cleanup button.

[image]

5. Click the Clean up system button.

[image]

6. Select the Previous Windows Installation(s) option to delete the Windows.old folder. Here you can also choose to delete other installation related files, including Windows upgrade log files and Temporary Windows installation files, which can take up several gigabytes of storage as well.

[image]

7. Click OK.
8. Click Delete Files on the pop-up dialog to confirm the deletion.
   On the Disk Cleanup warning click Yes to complete the process.